Display an Alert When User Session Expires in Laravel
I am using the Laravel framework and would like to create an alert when the session expires. I tried implementing a JavaScript code that checks if the user is logged in every three seconds as follows:
var refreshIntervalId = setInterval(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/check-auth',
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        success: function(response) {
            if (!response.authenticated) {
                swal("Sua sessão expirou. Por favor, faça login novamente!", "", "warning")
                .then(function(){ 
                    window.location.href = window.origin + '/login';
                });
                clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
            } 
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.error('AJAX request failed:', status, error);
        }
    });
}, 3000);


Additionally, I created a route to check if the user is logged in:
Route::middleware('bypass.session')->get('/check-auth', function () {
    return response()->json(['authenticated' => auth()->check()]);
});

Is there a better way to achieve this? The current logic accumulates cache in the browser and each AJAX request is considered a user interaction, which prevents the session from expiring.

you can change your interval with your SESSION_LIFETIME value (in minute) from .env file
default SESSION_LIFETIME value is 120 minute, then in setInterval must more than 120 minute, (for example 121 minute) for user not being interaction again.
var refreshIntervalId = setInterval(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/check-auth',
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        success: function(response) {
            if (!response.authenticated) {
                swal("Sua sessão expirou. Por favor, faça login novamente!", "", "warning")
                .then(function(){ 
                    window.location.href = window.origin + '/login';
                });
                clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
            } 
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.error('AJAX request failed:', status, error);
        }
    });
}, 7260000);

